# RegEx with variables in plot (visualization) alias in Grafana

Tags: regex, grafana, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have queries aliased as:

```
"Temperature $Names1" and "Power $Names1"
```

I would like my legend to read:

```
"Temperature &lt;name&gt;" and "Power &lt;name&gt;"
```

My legend works as expected, but I am trying to set an alias so I can plot the Power data on y-axis2 and set the color.

Under visualization in "alias or regex" I have typed:

```
/^Power $Names1$/
```

It seems though that the $ for my variable is terminating the regex.  I have tried various methods of escaping it but without success.

Maybe I am doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: What does the documentation say about variable string substitution? As with all regex engines, they are the last to get the string, so maybe you just need to read the doc's some more about strings and stop blaming the regex.

Answer (score -1):

[This link](https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/#regex) helps you to write a correct expression for Grafana.

### Example in Grafana

```
Regex
Formats multi-value variable into a regex string.

servers = ['test1.', 'test2']
String to interpolate: '${servers:regex}'
Interpolation result: '(test1\.|test2)'
```

Based on that, you might want to modify your variables that you are trying to pass.

Comment: I'm not really understanding I guess.  I tried:  /^Power ${Names1:regex}$/  but that does not seem to work either.